# How to get ClassValue in weka random forest?

Tags: java, weka

I use weka in java to build RandomForest. I want to get instance class double value.But I print the class value, it just 0 or 1. How to get double value? I want to get double value like '0.6',not just '0' or '1'.

```
Classifier model = new RandomForest();    
for (int i = 0; i < submitData.numInstances(); i++) {
    double clsLabel = model.classifyInstance(submitData.instance(i));
    outputData.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
}
```

Comment: In python,scikit-learn can print class double value.